# How to run program using CV for Face Detection?

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.7

Currently I'm trying to execute following code which uses Webcam for Face Detection using CV.

I have the following code and error message.

What shall I modify to be able to run my program?

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

**CODE**

```
import cv2

face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\harsh tiwari\.spyder-py3\opencv-4.2.0\opencv-4.2.0\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('Video',gray)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k==27:
        break

cap.release()
```

**ERROR**

> error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1533128839831\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11147: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor

Comment: Before `gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`, please check `if img is not None`

Comment: This code detects my face just fine on my machine with macOS Mojave, Python 3.8 and opencv-python 4.1.2. There might be an issue with the capture.

Comment: The problem is likely to be that no camera is detected. On Ubuntu, there should be at least one video devices listed with `ls -ltrh /dev/video*`. If that is the case, check  that the opencv version you are using is compiled with ffmpeg `python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())" | grep FFMPEG`

Comment: I'm using windows ,the problem persisted.I'm trying to update opencv but same problem exists